# Unity 3D e Android, como manipular arquivo txt?

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

Como fazer na `Unity 3D` ler um `arquivo txt` linha por linha e armazenar em um vetor utilizando C#.

Bom, eu consegui manipular o `arquivo .txt`, porém no `Android` ele não funciona.

Segue o código que usei.

```
int counter;
string line;
string[] teste = new string[10];
System.IO.StreamReader file;
file = new StreamReader("nome_do_arquivo.txt");

        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
             teste[counter] = line;

             counter++;
        }

        file.Close();
```

Esse código para pc resolve meu problema, porém eu preciso para *Android*, ao compilar para *Android* esse método não funciona, é como se ele não levasse o `.txt` junto ao `Apk`.

**Outra pergunta, na `Unity 3D` utilizado `C#` para `Android`, como manipular arquivos txt?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja esse exemplo que faz uma leitura linha por linha:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.IO;

public class LineReader : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected FileInfo theSourceFile = null;
    protected StreamReader reader = null;
    protected string text = " "; // permite que a primeira linha seja lida

    void Start () {
        theSourceFile = new FileInfo ("nome_do_arquivo.txt");
        reader = theSourceFile.OpenText();
    }

    void Update () {
        if (text != null) {
            text = reader.ReadLine();
            //Console.WriteLine(text);
            print (text);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

De acordo com a [Documentação](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html), você precisa de uma pastinha chamada **Resources**.

> Pathname of the target folder. When using the empty string (i.e., ""),
>   the function will load the entire contents of the Resources folder.

Agora com esse procedimento você já deve conseguir ler o arquivo no Android:

```
public static string Read(string filename) {
    //Load the text file using Reources.Load
    TextAsset theTextFile = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(filename);

    //There's a text file named filename, lets get it's contents and return it
    if(theTextFile != null)
        return theTextFile.text;

    //There's no file, return an empty string.
    return string.Empty;
}
```

E aqui no [Forum da Unity](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/516735/load-text-file-on-streaming-assets-in-android.html) uma pergunta com resposta Validada que pode exclarecer algumas duvidas!

**Edit:**

Varias formas de ler cada linha do arquivo:

```
public TextAsset TextFile; //Com essa variavel você pode jogar o arquivo pelo Inspetor 
void readTextFileLines() { 
    string[] linesInFile = TextFile.text.Split('\n');

    foreach (string line in linesInFile) //Para cada linha....
    {
        //Aqui você adiciona no seu vetor!
    }
}
```

Semelhante ao que você usa (que ficaria mais fácil ainda para você implementar!):

```
using System.IO;

void readTextFile(string file_path)
{
   StreamReader inp_stm = new StreamReader(file_path);

   while(!inp_stm.EndOfStream)
   {
       string inp_ln = stm.ReadLine( );
       // Do Something with the input. 
   }

   inp_stm.Close( );  
}
```

E por ai vai...

Comment: Com ele você pode ler o arquivo, e sim, pode usar parte do seu para poder popular o array! Estou sem pc com Unity aqui para ir ajudando nos testes!